# Why I need HasAndroidInjection to inject an inner Fragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have an `Activity` called `Activity1`, then inside has a `Fragment1` all have the `@ContributeAndroidInjection` and then if my `Activity2` wants to inject `Fragment1`

Why I need to implement `HasAndroidInjector` and do the

```
@Inject lateinit var androidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>
override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector
```

to be able to use a `Fragment` that is already with `@ContributeAndroidInjection` ? If I remove this two lines it says :

> RunTimeException:Unable to resume activity {MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

I thought that if I have this:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(
 modules = [ FragmentProvider::class]
)
fun bindMyActivity2: Activity2
```

It would work anyways, because I've add as a modules a module that has inside the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` with that Fragment...
Is it because I need that `hasAndroidInjector` when I want to provide injection into a inner `Fragment`?

Comment: Is it a typo that your method `bindMyActivity2` is not abstract?

Comment: No, I have like `@Module interface FeatureXModule{ @ContributesAndroidInjector fun provideFragment(): MyFragment}`

Comment: I may be wrong, but according to official dagger doc `@ContributesAndroidInjector` must be applied to an abstract method

Comment: I've tried it already... but nope. I mean I want to use a Fragment on my new Activity which has been added as a `@ContributeandroidInjector` before to use it on Activity1, so I need the presenter, repo, etc... but Adding it as a modules it would do the magic already... I don't know why I need that extra implements for hasAndroidInjection....

Comment: @Steyrix Any idea?